# RxJS Observable.fromEvent data

Tags: javascript, events, rxjs

How can I attach event data to a `Observable.fromEvent`?

In my example I have the following array of objects

```
var people = [
    { name: "Bert", img: "" },
    { name: "Enrie", img: "" },
    { name: "Elmo", img: "" }
];
```

I want to create a clickStream with a `data.src` something like:

```
clickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(li, 'click', { src :  people[p].img });
```

And then subscribe to it:

```
clickStream.subscribe(function(event) {
    $('#img')[0].src = event.data.src;
});
```

[API documentation for `fromEvent` method](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/fromevent.md)

**Edit**

I created a [JsFiddle of my example](https://jsfiddle.net/0gcckozp/1/), note in the console log the event has a `data` object which is undefined - How do I assign it?

Note: I am not using a event emitter but a native DOM event

Comment: The third parameter to fromEvent is meant to be a selector function - what if you use something like function() {return { src :  people[p].img }}?

Comment: Ahh okay thanks, the documentation wasn't very clear on that.
But this now replaces the whole event with the data object, I want to retain the event and just append the data to the event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if I understood properly your use case, but if you want to add something to the event object passed by the listener, then just do it with a `map`  :

```
clickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(li, 'click').map(function (event){
  return {
    event : event,
    data : { src :  people[p].img }
  }
});
```

This in particular will be better than inserting directly the `data` property in the event. `event` should be inmutable.

Or you could use the selector overload (to test, never actually used that selector function):

```
clickStream = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(li, 'click', function (event){
  return {
    event : event,
    data : { src :  people[p].img }
  }
});
```

Comment: I accepted this as the answer, I chose the second example using the `fromEvent` selector function - I think the official documentation should include a example using a native event, the only example they have is using `EventEmiter` which was confusing to me
I updated my JSFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/0gcckozp/1/

Answer (score 3):

You were pretty close.

Refers to the API documentation for the **fromEvent** method, the third argument should be a function which can take arguments, and return a single object.

so you have to do :

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent(li, 'click', _ => { return { src: elm.img } })
```

Then when you will subscribe to this, you will get an object with the **src** property.

Moreover, I have updated your code to make it in a **functional way**

```
  const people = [
        { name: "Bert", img: "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/muppet/images/e/e1/Bert_smile.png/revision/latest?cb=20110630173259" },
        { name: "Enrie", img: "http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/muppet/images/4/41/Ernie-RubberDuckie.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20110423180533" },
        { name: "Elmo", img: "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/74/Elmo_from_Sesame_Street.gif" }
    ];



  const ul = $('#list');

  const clickStream  = people.map((elm) => {
    const li = $('<li />');
    li.html(elm.name);
    li.data('src', elm.img);
    ul.append(li);
    return Rx.Observable.fromEvent(li, 'click', _ => { return { src: elm.img } })
  }).reduce((a, b) => Rx.Observable.merge(a, b), Rx.Observable.empty())

  clickStream.subscribe(e => console.log(e))
```

Feel free to check the updated [**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/paulB81/37kaLfqt/4/)

Comment: The `reduce` is unnecessary, just use `flatMap` instead of `map`

Comment: `people` is a JavaScript array not a Observable, it doesn't have a `flatMap` function

Comment: I gave this a up vote for the functional style, but I want to retain the `event` object not replace it with a new one